# python google-auth-oauthtool to get access token

Tags: python-3.x, google-assistant-sdk

I am using the python script as mentioned in the link https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/prototype/getting-started-other-platforms/integrate to get the access token.

But when run the google-auth-oauthtool in windows PC, i am getting an error

> OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

Can some one pls help to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

May be it's user permission issue or your using wrong port.

If it's user permission issue try this,In Windows OS  all accounts run programs in unprivileged mode by default.
there's no "Run as Administrator" context menu option for python script.
It's possible to use ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin() to detect whether the script has admin access, and ShellExecuteEx with the 'runas' verb on python.exe, with sys.argv[0] as a parameter to prompt the UAC dialog if needed.

Other wise it may be wrong port issue for that try this fix, just use the command on terminal like: netstat -na|findstr port, you will see the port has been used. So if you want to start the server without this message, you can change other port that not been used.